# How to put buttons in a table (html or php)

Tags: php, html

I want to put a button in the table at php.

here is my code.

```
         echo "<td>";?> <img src="<?php echo $row["image"]; ?>" height = "100" width = "100" border="1"> <?php echo "</td>"; //row에 값넣는 것
         echo "<td>" . $row['bookName'] . "</td>";
         echo "<td>" . $row['publisher'] . "</td>";
         echo "<td>" . $row['writer'] . "</td>";
         echo "<td>" . $row['libraryowned'] . "</td>";
         echo "<td>" . $row['codenumber'] . "</td>";
         // I want to button here
         echo "<td>" . $row['loan'] . "</td>";
         echo "<td>" . $row['publicationdate'] . "</td>";
         echo "<td>" . $row['reservation'] . "</td>";
         echo "<td>" . $row['borrowdate'] . "</td>";
         echo "<td>" . $row['returndate'] . "</td>";
         echo "<tr></tr>";
```

Comment: Ok, and where do you fail? What's the problem?

Comment: are u using form inside your tr, td and loop??

Answer (score 2):

just put a button element inside a  element like this:

```
<td><button></button></td>
```

if you like to refer to some script / page:

```
<td><a href="somescript.php?id=".$row['id']."><button></button></a></td>
```

You can put in the href part whatever you want. You can also omit the button element and heir your button-CSSClass to the `<a>` element.

I hope I helped you.
Have Fun!